# Why isn't the function action stays until refresh but suddenly vanishes after living the click

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, dom

> Here the function is working but the color on the `<p>` is does not stay for longer time as soon as i leave the button if comes to its original form

```js
function color(){
   document.getElementById("change").style.color = "#ff00ff";
}
```

### Html

```html
<p id="change"></p>
<button onclick="color()">Change</button>
```

Comment: Maybe you have another listeners on button/text, or another code changes it? Because onclick listener can't work like you dedcribe

Comment: Please refer [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and add a [Minimum Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: If you want the changes you made using javascript to stay, you need to save those changes in localstorage

Comment: buttons submit forms. Billions of dupes out there

Comment: Clicking a submit button submits a form which loads a new page immediately after the JS has finished modifying the DOM.

Answer (score -1):

works perfectly at mine, but try this

```
document.getElementById('button_id').addEventListener('click', color)
```

Comment: If you can't reproduce the problem, and don't understand the cause of the problem, then throwing code at the wall in the hope that it sticks does not make for a good answer.